# com.android.volley.AuthFailureError - Android

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get a list of all users, but I keep getting this error:

```
E/Volley: [2074] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://myappurl.com
```

and

```
I/System.out: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
```

in my code I have:

```
{
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String creds = String.format("%s:%s","EMAIL","PASSWORD");
            String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            params.put("Authorization", auth);
            return params;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? I've never made a "header" before, so I'm kinda flying by the seat of my pants right now.

Comment: Most probably, the data you are sending with Authorization header is not what server is expecting to authorize you. Best approach - print the header data, show it to server-side developer(s) and ask them if you are sending something wrong.

Comment: If you are using firebase see what header firebase requires for authorization

Comment: Try putting ur firebase access token in the authorization header